# Using keyword with Rake

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

#Using rake(short for Rapid Automatic Keyword Extraction algorithm) for the text preprocessing.RAKE is a keyword extraction algorithm that extracts those key phrases in a text corpus by determining the frequency of words and their relative occurrence with other words in the corpus.

## to extract key words from Plot to a list

```
df['Key_words'] = ''   # initializing a new column
r = Rake()   # using Rake to remove stop words

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    r.extract_keywords_from_text(row['Plot'])   # to extract key words 
    key_words_dict_scores = r.get_word_degrees()    # to get dictionary with key words and their similarity scores
    row['Key_words'] = list(key_words_dict_scores.keys())   # to assign it to new column

df
```

I am expecting the Key words should be written as a new colon however it returns a lookup error. I didn't use it before so I don't even have idea for what reason

### MY ERROR

```
LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      6 
      7 for index, row in df.iterrows():
----> 8     r.extract_keywords_from_text(row['Plot'])   # to extract key words
      9     key_words_dict_scores = r.get_word_degrees()    # to get dictionary with key words and their similarity scores
     10     row['Key_words'] = list(key_words_dict_scores.keys())   # to assign it to new column

c:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rake_nltk\rake.py in extract_keywords_from_text(self, text)
    124         :param text: Text to extract keywords from, provided as a string.
    125         """
--> 126         sentences: List[Sentence] = self._tokenize_text_to_sentences(text)
    127         self.extract_keywords_from_sentences(sentences)
    128 

c:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rake_nltk\rake.py in _tokenize_text_to_sentences(self, text)
    178         :return: List of sentences as per the tokenizer used.
```